# What is wrong with my webgl shader program: it throws no errors in the console?

Tags: javascript, webgl, shader

I checked for errors and validate the program and it fails to validate but the shaders compile and the program links fine. I, for the life of me, don't understand why there are warnings saying invalid program and yetthe shaders compile and it links correctly.

```js
function log(msg) {
  var pre = document.createElement("pre");
  pre.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg));
  document.body.appendChild(pre);
}

function init() {
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  var gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');
  var vertexShaderText = document.querySelector("#vs").text;
  var fragmentShaderText = document.querySelector("#fs").text;
  shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
  // compilation stuff here

  //
  // Create shaders
  //
  vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
  fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);

  gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, vertexShaderText);
  gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, fragmentShaderText);

  gl.compileShader(vertexShader);
  if (!gl.getShaderParameter(vertexShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
    log('ERROR compiling vertex shader!', gl.getShaderInfoLog(vertexShader));
    return;
  }

  gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);
  if (!gl.getShaderParameter(fragmentShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
    log('ERROR compiling fragment shader!', gl.getShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader));
    return;
  }

  shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
  gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
  gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
  gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);
  if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
    log('ERROR linking program!', gl.getProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram));
    return;
  }
  gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);
  // make sure you have vertex, vertex normal, and texture coordinate
  // attributes located in your shaders and attach them to the shader program
  if (!shaderProgram) {
    log('no shader');
    return;
  }
  if (!gl.validateProgram(shaderProgram)) {
    log("info: " + gl.getProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram));
    return;
  }
  log("success");
}
init();
```

```html
<script id="vs" type="notjs">
precision mediump float;

attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
attribute vec3 aVertexNormal;
attribute vec3 aTextureCoord;
varying vec3 fragTextCoord;
void main()
{
  fragTextCoord = aVertexPosition;
  gl_Position = vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
}
</script>
<script id="fs" type="notjs">
precision mediump float;

varying vec3 fragTextCoord;
uniform sampler2D sampler;

void main()
{
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(sampler, vec2(fragTextCoord[0],fragTextCoord[1]));
}
</script>
```

Comment: I've never seen `fragTextCoord[0]` (that way of accessing the element) before, is it legal?

Comment: @MiJyn, yes that's legal. @A W, next time please consider this when asking for debugging help [Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary** to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I understand that however the code above is necessary to give context to the question. Believe me the project I am working on is many files big, this is just one part of one file.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong with your shader program

The code in your question is checking the result of `gl.validateProgram` which returns nothing. Nothing is `UNDEFINED` so the if statement

```
if (!gl.validateProgram(...))
```

will always be true.

As [per the docs](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glValidateProgram.xml) to validate a program you do this

```
gl.validateProgram(someProgram);
if (!gl.getProgramParameter(someProgram, gl.VALIDATE_STATUS)) {
  // validation failed
}
```

Here's the fixed code

```js
function log(msg) {
  var pre = document.createElement("pre");
  pre.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg));
  document.body.appendChild(pre);
}

function init() {
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  var gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');
  var vertexShaderText = document.querySelector("#vs").text;
  var fragmentShaderText = document.querySelector("#fs").text;
  shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
  // compilation stuff here

  //
  // Create shaders
  //
  vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
  fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);

  gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, vertexShaderText);
  gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, fragmentShaderText);

  gl.compileShader(vertexShader);
  if (!gl.getShaderParameter(vertexShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
    log('ERROR compiling vertex shader!', gl.getShaderInfoLog(vertexShader));
    return;
  }

  gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);
  if (!gl.getShaderParameter(fragmentShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
    log('ERROR compiling fragment shader!', gl.getShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader));
    return;
  }

  shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
  gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
  gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
  gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);
  if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
    log('ERROR linking program!', gl.getProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram));
    return;
  }
  gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);
  // make sure you have vertex, vertex normal, and texture coordinate
  // attributes located in your shaders and attach them to the shader program
  if (!shaderProgram) {
    log('no shader');
    return;
  }
  
  gl.validateProgram(shaderProgram);
  if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.VALIDATE_STATUS)) {
    log("info: " + gl.getProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram));
    return;
  }
  log("success");
  getAttribLoc("aVertexPosition");
  getAttribLoc("aVertexNormal");
  getAttribLoc("aTextureCoord");
  getUniformLoc("sampler");


  function getAttribLoc(name) {
    var loc = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, name);
    log("attribute: '" + name + "' location " +  (loc >= 0 ? ("= " + loc) : "does not exist or was optimized away"));
  }

  function getUniformLoc(name) {
    var loc = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, name);
    log("uniform: '" + name + "' " + (loc ? "exists" : "does not exist or was optimized away"));
  }
}
init();
```

```html
<script id="vs" type="notjs">
precision mediump float;

attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
attribute vec3 aVertexNormal;
attribute vec3 aTextureCoord;
varying vec3 fragTextCoord;
void main()
{
  fragTextCoord = aVertexPosition;
  gl_Position = vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
}
</script>
<script id="fs" type="notjs">
precision mediump float;

varying vec3 fragTextCoord;
uniform sampler2D sampler;

void main()
{
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(sampler, vec2(fragTextCoord[0],fragTextCoord[1]));
}
</script>
```

Comment: you cannot pass a shader to getProgramParameter but even if you pass program it fine okay and the shaders compile fine but the line:   shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexPosition") returns undefined.

Comment: That was a typo on my part (fixed). The point is `gl.validateProgram` returns nothing so you can't check its return value. You have to check the `gl.getProgramParameter(prg, gl.VALIDATE_STATUS)` As for `aVertexPosition` it works for me. Added working example